# Create two foreign key from one table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I am creating user table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TblUser 
(
     UserId int identity primary key, 
     Name varchar(20)
)
```

AND creating one more table

```
CREATE TABLE TblAnnouncements 
(
     Id int identity primary key,
     Announcements varchar(20),
     CreatedBy INT 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TblUser (USERID)  
            ON DELETE  CASCADE, 
     UpdatedBy INT 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TblUser (USERID)  
            ON DELETE SET NULL
)
```

I am getting this error

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK__TblAnnoun__Updat__60A75C0F' on table 'TblAnnouncements' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How to maintain `createdby` and `updatedby` in a table?

Can you suggest any other way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: You should *always* give you foreign key constraints **explicit names** so you don't have to deal with `FK__TblAnnoun__Updat__60A75C0F` ....

Answer (score -1):

Try to create FK constraints after creating the plain table. i.e ALTER TABLE ADD Constraint syntax